# PC Controller not working with Arkham Origins

Tags: controllers, batman-arkham-origins

I recently bought a PC Controller. It wasn't working with The Amazing Spiderman 2. I updated all the drivers and stuff but all in vain. I did some research and found that the games require a **Xiinput** file thingy. I placed it in the game directory and the controller worked smoothly on TASM2. I brought Batman AO yesterday. I pasted the files in the game's directory but **IS ISN'T WORKING.**
Is it a problem with my controller or with the game?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should include what kind of controller it is and possibly the driver.  Personally, I hooked up an xbox 360 receiver and use a wireless 360 controller and it works fine.

Comment: @boiledham That's not a surprise.  XInput was written with the Xbox 360 controller in mind.

Comment: @Powerlord It's part of why I picked the 360 controller to use with my PC :)

Comment: Its a Microsmart Gamepad MC371. It comes with a CD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many games these days are built with the XBOX 360 controller in mind, so often times 3rd party controllers won't work very well or sometimes even at all, unless they are taken into account by the developer.

However, I'm able to use my Logitech controller without issue on these sorts of games using [x360ce](https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce), which is a controller emulator that allows you to map your controller to the proper controls. And it also tries to download configuration files online based on the game and the controller in an attempt to automatically configure things when possible.

To use it, download the program, copy it into the Arkham Origins directory, and run the software. It should show you a picture of the 360 controller where you can test and map your controller to the right buttons.